# PyMC3: How can I code my custom distribution with observed data better for Theano?

Tags: pymc, pymc3

I am attempting to implement a fairly simple model in pymc3. The gist is that I have some data that is generated from a sequence of random choices. The choices can be thought of as a multinomial, and the process selects choices as a function of previous choices.

The overall probability of the categories is modeled with a Dirichlet prior.

The likelihood function must be customized for the data at hand. The data are lists of 0's and 1's that are output from the process. I have successfully made the model in pymc2, which you can find at [this blog post](https://phaethonprime.wordpress.com/2015/06/25/bayesian-modeling-with-pymc-dirichlet-and-a-custom-stochastic/). Here is a python function that generates test data for this problem:

```py
ps = [0.2,0.35,0.25,0.15,0.0498,1/5000]
def make(ps):
    out = []
    while len(out) < 5:
        n_spots = 5-len(out)
        sp = sum(ps[:n_spots+1])
        P = [x/sp for x in ps[:n_spots+1]]
        l = np.argwhere(np.random.multinomial(1,P)==1).ravel()[0]
        #if len(out) == 4:
        #    l = np.argwhere(np.random.multinomial(1,ps[:2])==1).ravel()[0]
        out.extend([1]*l)
        if (out and out[-1] == 1 and len(out) < 5) or l == 0:
            out.append(0)
        #print n_spots, l, len(out)
    assert len(out) == 5
    return out
```

As I'm learning/moving to pymc3, I'm trying to input my data as observed into a custom likelihood function, and I'm running into several issues along the way. It's probably because this is my first experience with Theano, but I'm hoping that someone can give some advice.

Here is my code (using the make function above):

```py
import numpy as np
import pymc3 as pm
from scipy import optimize
import theano.tensor as T
from theano.compile.ops import as_op
from collections import Counter

# This function gets the attributes of the data that are relevant for calculating the likelihood 
def scan(value):
    groups = []
    prev = False
    s = 0
    for i in xrange(5):
        if value[i] == 0:
            if prev:
                groups.append((s,5-(i-s)))
                prev = False
                s = 0
            else:
                groups.append((0,5-i))
        else:
            prev = True
            s += 1
    if prev:
        groups.append((s,4-(i-s)))
    return groups

# The likelihood calculation for a single data point
def like1(v,p):
    l = 1
    groups = scan(v)
    for n, s in groups:
        l *= p[n]/p[:s+1].sum()
    return T.log(l)

# my custom likelihood class
class CustomDist(pm.distributions.Discrete):
    def __init__(self, ps, data, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CustomDist, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.ps = ps
        self.data = data

    def logp(self,v):
        all_l = 0
        for v, k in self.data.items():
            l = like1(v,self.ps)
            all_l += l*k
        return all_l

# model creation
model = pm.Model()

with model:
    probs = pm.Dirichlet('probs',a=np.array([0.5]*6),shape=6,testval=np.array([1/6.0]*6))
    output = CustomDist("rolls",ps=probs,data=data,observed=True)
```

I am able to find the MAP in about a minute or so (my machine is Windows 7, i7-4790 @3.6GHz). The MAP matches well with the input probability vector, which at least means the model is linked properly.

When I try to do traces, though, my memory usage skyrockets (up to several gig) and I haven't actually been patient enough for the model to finish compiling. I've waited 10 minutes + for the NUTS or HMC to compile before even tracing. The metropolis stepping works just fine, though (and is much faster than with pymc2).

Am I just being too hopeful for Theano to be able to handle for-loops of non-theano data well? Is there a better way to write this code so that Theano plays well with it, or am I limited because my data is a custom python type and can't be analyzed with array/matrix operations?

Thanks in advance for your advice and feedback. Please let me know what might need clarification!

Comment: What version of Theano are you using?  For me this code leads to an `AsTensorError` when instantiating the `CustomDist`: `Cannot cast True or False as a tensor variable. Please use 1 or 0. This error might be caused by using the == operator on Variables. v == w does not do what you think it does, use theano.tensor.eq(v, w) instead.`